# Small php improvement code needed of <p> tag

Tags: php

I am displaying in prices and cost using below code, where what happens if

```
<p>+ Duty: Rs. 
<?php 
echo (round($r));
?> 

<p>+ Cess: Rs. 
<?php 
echo ($l);
?> 

<p>
<?php 
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 10000)
            {   
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs";

            }   
 ?>

 <p><b> Net Cost </b>: Rs.
```

if cost of good is above 10000 - then

```
Duty
+ Cess
+ TCS
Net Cost
```

However if cost less than 10000 then output shown as below with a gap in between cess and net cost in line

```
  Duty
+ Cess

Net Cost
```

I understand it due to 'p' tag
If i remove

tag then it will be shown as below (if price > 10000)

```
 Duty
+ Cess + TCS
Net Cost
```

Could you suggest on position of

tag - so that it can execute only when cost > 10000

```
this also does not work

<?php 
$a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
if($a > 10000)
            {   
             <p> 
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs";
             </p>   
            }   
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all opened tags are closed

```
<p>+ Duty: Rs. 
   <?php   echo (round($r));   ?> 
</p>

<p>+ Cess: Rs. 
   <?php  echo ($l); ?> 
</p> 

<?php 
   $a = $this->prodDet->v_price;
   if($a > 10000)
            {   
                echo '<p>';
                $tcs=(round(.01*$a));
                echo "+ TCS: Rs. $tcs";
                echo '</p>';
            }   
 ?>    
 <p><b> Net Cost </b>: Rs. </p>
```